# Parsing json data from internet

Tags: android, json

Right now I have an android app that display a graph plot of data that is feed to it form Json file. Currently I have a json file in my asset folder from which I am fetching the data for the graph plot. But what I actually want is that:

I have a json file on cloud (GCP Bucket). 
I want to get that data from the json file or the json itself from cloud bucket and get it to the app so that graph plot can be made.
The json file can be updated, hence the latest data will be fetched by the android app for the graph plot.

Please suggest me any method to do so?

Comment: download the file, and use it same way as from assets

Comment: No, but I want this to happen within the app itself. Mens if I press a button on the app latest json file from the cloud should be fetched.

Comment: then `download the file` programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this documentation https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/using-cloud-storage

You can call the api using async task.

Or are you facing any specific problem calling the api?

There is also post regarding this [How to read a file from Google Cloud Storage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121510/how-to-read-a-file-from-google-cloud-storage-in-java)

Comment: But in case of Android what about the "path to key" and "download directory path"

Answer (score 0):

you can read and write any file on GCP Bucket in Android. just read file using this library in single line of code

https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage

after read json file you can write that file in your app storage if you need it to use later.

Comment: What should be the destination directory for download in case of android.

Comment: you can get external storage directory in android using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`