# How to read a text file from Google cloud platform using API

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need to read a text file from Google cloud platform through GET request. Am gonna use ajax to make the call from the java script function and display it in my dashboard. I found this endpoint in GCP site
GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/example-bucket/o/foo%2f%3fbar 
how to add authentication to this?And is this the right endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

The API to obtain the GCS object data is documented here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get

This matches the URL example that you have found.  Take note of the `alt=media` query property to get the content of the object as opposed to its metadata.

For security, please read the following on access control options:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a perfectly good endpoint (although for that path, you'll need to specify that you want the contents of the file and not the metadata using the alt parameter: `https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket/o/foo%2fbar?alt=media` )

You could also use the slightly more readable path `https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/foo`.

Auth can be managed in a few ways. Google Cloud APIs most frequently use OAuth. After doing bit of a dance, you end up with a temporary access key. The access key is usually passed as an HTTP header of the pattern `Authorization: Bearer some.lengthykey`.

If you have the `gcloud` app installed and you've set up your account with it, you can fetch a key like this: `gcloud auth print-access-token`.

So, from the Linux command prompt, here's a quick example of downloading an object:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer `gcloud auth print-access-token`" \ 
    https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/object`.
```

There are a number of other schemes to handle auth as well (signed URLs, service account keys, signed policy documents, application default credentials), depending on your needs, but that's the most straightforward.

Comment: Thanks!! Actually my text file is inside multiple object(folders) under the bucket
So do I have to give the entire path in the place of object? I get 400 error when I give entire path or even just give the file name in place of object
And can this be executed from post man once using OAuth authentication?

Comment: For the "/storage/v1" path, remember to escape slashes in the object name. For the other path, it's not necessary.  Also, I'm not famliar with Postman, but I see that there are some articles about using it with this style of auth: https://medium.com/@pnatraj/google-cloud-api-with-postman-f4cf070e665f

Comment: I tried the curl command from putty but file gets downloaded with the below content
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
My bucket does exist

Comment: Just to be clear, you got "NoSuchBucket" from a URL beginning "https://storage.googleapis.com/nameOfYourBucketHere/" ?

Comment: Sorry,I had given the wrong bucket name.This was just the start for me, am actually trying to read the file through the GCP libraries and saw your solution in the this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121510/how-to-read-a-file-from-google-cloud-storage-in-java. Am getting  java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address in this line  Blob blob = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME, OBJECT_NAME);
Can you help me with what could be the issue?

Comment: Well, that's a weird one. You definitely shouldn't be running into invalid certificates. Is it possible that you are behind a corporate firewall or equivalent that's trying to swap out a certificate and is misconfigured?