# Is there a way load a GCS file instead of first downloading it and then opening it in your programming language

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've a ML-model stored on a Google Storage Bucket, but now I'm having some trouble using it.
I thought instead of first downloading the model (1.25GB) I could just direcly load the data into the memory, but I couldn't really find any documentation on this.

So I want to instantly get file data into a variable, is this possible?

Comment: In which language do you want to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition, you could use [Streaming Transfers](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming).

> Cloud Storage supports streaming transfers, which allow you to stream
>   data to and from your Cloud Storage account without requiring that the
>   data first be saved to a file. Streaming transfers are useful when you
>   want to upload data generated from a process directly into Cloud
>   Storage, or when you want to download data from Cloud Storage into a
>   process.

As explained in the documentation, you can use the third party [boto client library plugin for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-plugin#streaming-transfers) to utilize this tool.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by usign the download_as_string function (Python only).
https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/blob.html#Blob.download_as_string
But this requires to convert the data from bytes into the preferred type

```
blob = bucket.blob(storage_name)
x = blob.download_as_string()
print(x.decode('utf-8'))
```

In Java you can probably use this:
[How to read a file from Google Cloud Storage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121510/how-to-read-a-file-from-google-cloud-storage-in-java)
but I haven't tried it.