# Null pointer exception while trying to read file from Google cloud storage using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use Spring Boot to read a file stored in GCS using this tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/spring-cloud-gcp-gcs#4

My code as follows:

```
Resource gcsFile = resourceLoader.getResource(gcsPath);
            //InputStream inputStream = gcsFile.getInputStream();
            return StreamUtils.copyToString(
                    gcsFile.getInputStream(),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

`resourceLoader` is injected as a dependency using `@Autowired` annotation. The `gcsPath` variable is a String to the gcs file location (example: `gs://REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_BUCKET/my-file.txt`).

I get the below exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:878)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId.of(BlobId.java:109)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.storage.GoogleStorageResource.getBlobId(GoogleStorageResource.java:108)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.storage.GoogleStorageResource.resolve(GoogleStorageResource.java:113)
        at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.storage.GoogleStorageResource.getInputStream(GoogleStorageResource.java:167)
```

During debugging, I found that the following line is what triggers this exception:

`InputStream inputStream = gcsFile.getInputStream();`

I have not been able to figure out how and why this is happening. Can someone please help?

Comment: Looks like the pathto the file is incorrect

Comment: This is not the error, the error is that RRR does not initialize properly the stream. More information here actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121510/how-to-read-a-file-from-google-cloud-storage-in-java

Comment: @Jens No the path to the file is correct.

Comment: @NeatNerd The link doesn't help. I can use the standard Java API, but in this case the Spring API needs to be used. The issue happens only with the String API. Can you please point out what stream has not been initiated correctly and why?